# Are certain particle collisions more elastic than others?

Tags: collision, air, molecules, molecular-dynamics

If you have molecules of air colliding compared to a different element, will one be more elastic?

So if 2 molecules of some other element collide, will that be more or less elastic than 2 air molecules colliding?

For example, if said molecule had a higher mass than an air molecule. Would that change anything?

Comment: What would "more elastic" even mean? Collisions are either elastic or inelastic in the microscopic realm.

Comment: If you are thinking of "super elastic" then these do not exist in nature. Energy (matter) never spontaneously appear.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I’m not too familiar with this subject, but couldn’t the collision only loose some of the KE? Couldn’t it be in between elastic and inelastic?

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision

Comment: @my2cts thanks that helps, but unless I missed something, do different types of molecules experience more elastic collisions?

Comment: @Wyatt Internal degrees of freedom can absorb part of the kinetic energy in a collision. You should think of rotation, vibration and electronic excitations.  For different molecules the energies involved vary quite a bit and it also depends of the collision energy.

Comment: It is about definitions. For macroscopic objects, we can have essentially a continous fraction of kinetic energy converted to other forms of energy. However, for microscopic collisions, it is either fully elastic, or not, and everything that is not fully elastic is called inelastic.